# Adding latitude and longitude to QGIS file without losing the current xy coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I plan to convert a `.dwg`-file to QGIS. The coordinate system of the `.dwg`-file is set up in feet in the x and y directions from a point near the bottom center of the drawing. This coordinate system makes it easy to measure the size and distances between the various features in the drawing.

But after converting to QGIS, I would like to add latitude and longitude coordinates to the QGIS file so that the various features in the drawing can be located on the ground using a GPS app on a cell phone.

How can I add GPS coordinates to the QGIS file without having to give up the existing coordinate system in feet?

Answer (score 6):

Use Field Calculator with transform. Change `'EPSG:3006'` to your coordinate system code.

latitude:  `y(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:3006', 'EPSG:4326')`

longitude:     `x(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:3006', 'EPSG:4326')`

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the coordinates of the current drawing just measure the E to W and N to S distances of various geographical features on the ground from a central point on the ground. This central point actually exists on the ground but QGIS doesn't know where this central point is actually located. 

What I want to do is to tell QGIS the GPS location of the central point so that all of the features in the drawing can be located by GPS coordinates.